# getting a button to act as a link in Javascirpt inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to create a table that goes through all my files in my public_html folder and makes a directory out of the files with a button that will open a new window linked to the specified file. Here is my code:

```
function makeDirectory(data) {
    var display = document.getElementById("content");

    var directory = "<table><tr><th>File Name</th><th>File Type</th><th>CWD</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        directory += "<tr><td>" + data[i].fileName + "</td><td>" + data[i].fileType +

        "</td><td>" + data[i].cwd;
        if (data[i].fileType == "file") {

            directory += "</td><td>" +
                "<button onclick='window.open(data[i].fileName)'>Click to Display</button>" +
                "</td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            directory += "</td></tr>";
        }


        directory += "</table>";

    }

    display.innerHTML = directory;

}
```

The table comes out nicely with buttons next to every file but they don't do anything when they are clicked. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`onclick='window.open(data[i].fileName)'`
```

Write **data[i].fileName** literally as a string. Change into the JS format.

```
onclick='window.open("' + data[i].fileName + '")'
```

The final string is (edited because it's already inside a string)

```
directory += "</td><td>" +
                "<button onclick=\"window.open('" + data[i].fileName + "')\">Click to Display</button>" +
                "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question. I typed in exactly what you gave me and my table disappeared from the page.. any other thoughts?

Comment: @Megan Look my edit. See how I play with the quotes and escapes

Comment: yes I keep playing with quotes and escapes too but I can't seem to make it happy. thanks for trying to help! I will continue to mess with it and see if I can make anything happen.

Comment: It shouldn't be like that if you copy paste exactly from my example.. Either way, try to do a `console.log(directory)` to debug if there is any syntax problem in the pre-generated HTML.

Comment: that got it working I was just missing ">" thanks again!